# datalist not taking value on updatecommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have following code:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) {
                bindList();
            }
        }

    protected void dlAgents_EditCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        dlAgents.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        bindList();
    }

protected void dlAgents_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem | e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) {
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName")).Text = e.Item.DataItem("AgentName");
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblAddress")).Text = e.Item.DataItem("Address");
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblContactNo")).Text = e.Item.DataItem("ContactNo");
        ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkLoginID")).Text = e.Item.DataItem("LoginEmailID");
    }
}

protected void dlAgents_UpdateCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{


    GC.ExecuteCommand("update AgentMaster set Address='" + ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtAddress")).Text + "' , ContactNo='" + ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtContact")).Text + "' where agentid='" + e.CommandArgument + "'");
    dlAgents.EditItemIndex = -1;
    bindList();
}
```

In this code, for updatecommand, its always taking blank value for textboxes .. eg. `(TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtAddress")).Text` this textbox is blank, thats why not able to update with proper values.

Please help me.

Comment: using textbox for edit mode see aspx : http://pastie.org/8394228

Comment: I never used datalist in a long time, i suggest you not to use inline sql statements which is a very bad for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the ItemTemplate you have directly these controls this would work fine, but if not then it is not. As far as I know the FindControl Method is not recursive.

Try to find controls with this method:

```
    public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control control, string id)
    {

        if (control == null) return null;


        Control c = control.FindControl(id);

        if (c == null)
        {
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            {
                c = FindControlRecursive(child, id);
                if (c != null) break;
            }
        }

        return c;
    }
```